# Are refugees forced across the Mediterranean Sea by traffickers against their will?

Tags: europe, refugees

So far media has painted the picture that African refugees crossing the Mediterranean Sea pay huge sums to traffickers to be brought to Europe.

In an interview with [BR24](https://br24.de/nachrichten/kapitaen-fluechtlinge-wissen-nicht-worauf-sie-sich-einlassen,QxzACla) Claus-Peter Reisch, captain of the rescue ship Lifeline, says the following:

> Die Flüchtlinge, die da losgeschickt werden, die steigen ja oftmals gar nicht freiwillig ein. Wenn Flüchtlinge nicht einsteigen am Strand, dann werden halt einfach mal ein paar erschossen, dann steigt der Rest schon ein.

*The refugees, that are sent away there, they often don't board [the ships] willingly. If refugees don't board at the beach, then they just shoot a couple of them, then the rest boards.*

So far I was under the impression the refugees paid the traffickers, not that they were forced.
So, is it true, that refugees are forced across the Mediterranean Sea by traffickers?
If so, an answer as to why the traffickers would be behaving like that would be welcome as well.

Comment: Is that translation yours?

Comment: @DenisS Yes. Translated it myself.

Comment: As I read that (the original in Germsn,)  it sounds more like people actually do want to get to Europe, but don't want to get in the boats.  They aren't being forced to go to Europe.  They are being forced into the boats. From other things I've read, that would be because even people who don't know much about boats can see that the boats aren't safe and/or to small for the number of "passengers."

Comment: @JRE Thats a possible interpretation. But that would still beg the question as to why the traffickers would force the refugees into the boats. I would assume they have already been paid by then.

Comment: @JRE Also, following that logic, one would assume it would be safer to just row the boat out of sight of the traffickers and head back to safety.

Comment: Sure.  But what they are doing is illegal.  They want those people out of there.  As well, there are only so many spots they can operate from.  The authorities know those places.  The trafficers don't want to be standing around, arguing with a refugee who has good sense when the police show up.  Shoot a couple, ship the rest, disappear with the profits, do it all again next week.

Comment: @Syren Baran "I would assume they have already been paid" apparently, according to multiple sources online, they haven't been paid and are forcing them into slavery until they've paid their bill.

Comment: @DenisS Got some links to those sources? I cant really see how the traffickers could enforce that slavery once the refugees are in Europe.

Comment: Also, if you listen to the rest of the interview, the guy tells you that the refugees have mostly never seen a sea before.  Thay know absolute jack about navigation.

Comment: And, at that point, the refugess HAVE paid.  If they back out they are broke and stuck in a place that doesn't want them.

Comment: @SyrenBaran it's before they leave, while they're still in Libya.  https://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2016/oct/18/70-of-migrants-to-europe-from-north-africa-trafficked-or-exploited-un-united-nations-survey

Comment: @JRE I listened to the complete video. Obviously a lot of the refugees have never seen the ocean, and presumably even fewer Europe.
But that doesnt answer the question as to why the traffickers force refugees into boats at gun point. As you said, at that point they should have been paid.

Comment: I mean, for all i know the situation could be explained kinda like "Hey, i sold a kidney to pay you $3k for a boat trip. That aint a boat. I want my money back." BAMM "Anyone else want a bigger boat?". But thats just a guess, thats why i am asking.

Comment: That's about the size of it.

Comment: @SyrenBaran from what I understand they sell women and girls into slavery, force the men into boats and dump them on the NGOs they have contracted to take them to Europe. That's no doubt not a universal modus operandi, but that's what seems to be happening.